# Can't understand Google cloud platform pricing terms. Can i use it for hosting my website images?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Hey i have website and since traffic is high i wish to host my images in
google cloud storage. Is that a good option to reduce my server load?

And when i go through google cloud storage pricing section in
https://cloud.google.com/storage/
It is showing RETRIEVAL PRICING Free for Multi-Regional and AT REST PRICING $0.026 per GB/month.

What does RETRIEVAL and AT REST means? Bandwidth and disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. "At rest pricing" means the ongoing charge of keeping your objects in GCS. That's basically disk space.

"Retrieval Pricing" is the fee for fetching data, which is zero for multi-regional and regional buckets. However, keep in mind that there is also a fee for data egress from the network (throughput).

There's a more in-depth explanation at https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing.